# Not able to delete a xml file using unlink() in perl

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to delete an xml file using unlink() but it is not deleting it.

I am using it as follows:

```
$file_loc = catfile( home_directory_path(), "builds","data.xml" );
unlink($file_loc);
```

I am able to access the file while parsing it.
What's wrong? is `unlink()` not supposed to delete xml files?

Comment: If you open a filehandle to the file before calling `unlink`, you will still be able to use the filehandle until you close it. The file isn't completely deleted until all hard links to it are removed and all filehandles are closed.

Answer (score 5):

Please include error checking in your code.  You'll need this to figure out why unlink is not working:

```
unlink $file_loc or warn "Could not unlink $file_loc: $!";
```

This is from [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html).

Comment: For mac it is working fine but for windows it is giving permission denied error